# Eclipse keeps giving error message. can someone help? im new in java btw

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

        System.out.println("Do You Agree?");
        char c = (char) System.in.read();
        switch (c) {
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                System.out.println("You answered Yes");
                break;

            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                System.out.println("You answered NO");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Your answer is not Valid!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The error message:
[image: The error message]

Comment: Please include errors messages as *text* rather than as images - and as the image shows, there's a compilation error. You should be able to see that in the Errors view, and I suspect you were warned about it when you tried to run the code. You should almost *never* try to run code that doesn't compile - fix the compilation error instead.

Comment: Look at the line containing the red exclamation mark and the squiggly lines. Don't attempt to run your code before all these things are solved.

Comment: Please check your formatting. The code your posted is not formatted correct. If done so, you would not be able to post your question, as it does not contain enough non-code text. Which should give you a hint, that we prefere to have more than just code.

Comment: Is there a time that it's ok to run uncompilable code?

Answer (score 0):

In the Error message, you see the Exception turns up in the Java Runtime Environment - also called JRE. That means it tries to execute your Program, but it appeared to have an unresolved Compilation Problem.

Simply put, there was something wrong at the time you actually tried to compile your Code in Eclipse.

Try to **Rebuild** or **Clean your Project**, before you build and execute it again and the Error should be fixed prior to the next Execution.